# Is shared defense a zone effect or a granted boon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, paladin

For the Paladin, a Divine Defender, this is an alternative to a mercy.

> Shared Defense (Su)
>
> At 3rd level, a divine defender can spend one use of her lay on hands
>   ability as a standard action to grant all adjacent allies (including
>   paladins) a bonus. At 3rd level, adjacent allies receive a +1 sacred
>   bonus to their AC and CMD and on their saving throws. These bonuses
>   last for a number of rounds equal to the divine defender’s Charisma
>   modifier.

My question is, is the bonus granted only to those who are adjacent to me for the entire duration, like a zone centered on the Paladin? Or is it granted to those who are adjacent to me when the effect goes off, and then when they move away they keep the boon for the designated rounds (which in my case would be 4)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a zone. They have to stay near you for them to receive the bonus. The description in the PFSRD goes into a greater explanation.

[Divine Defender - Shared Defense](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin/archetypes/paizo---paladin-archetypes/divine-defender)

Here is the text:

> Shared Defense (Su)
>
> At 3rd level, a divine defender can spend one use of her lay on hands ability as a standard action to grant all adjacent allies (including paladins) a bonus. At 3rd level, adjacent allies receive a +1 sacred bonus to their AC and CMD and on their saving throws. These bonuses last for a number of rounds equal to the divine defender’s Charisma modifier. At 9th level and 15th level, this bonus increases by +1. At 6th level, these bonuses are granted to all allies within 10 feet, and allies that are at fewer than 0 hit points within this area are automatically stabilized. At 12th level, these bonuses are granted to all allies within 15 feet, and allies within this area are immune to bleed damage. At 18th level, these bonuses are granted to all allies within 20 feet, and allies within this area gain a 25% chance to negate any sneak attack or critical hit scored against them. This ability does not stack with the chance provided from the light, medium, or heavy fortification armor special abilities. These bonuses are cumulative with each other. **Allies only benefit from these bonuses while in the listed area.**
>
> This ability replaces mercy.